# Web + Mobile Chat Server Application

Tags: php, android, node.js, websocket, chat

Hello i am building a chat server, what i used to do before was set a timer that posts a blank json object to the server to check for any chat updates in the database and return such data to the client side using jquery ajax, i have however come across some technologies like websockets and node.js which i would like to implement in my application.  The thing is that the applicationno i am building is a web application but a colleague of mine is also building an android app with the exact same functionality that should communicate with the same sever, i would not like to re-write my chat code for the mobile android version too, i simply want to write one piece of code that can be used for both web and mobile platforms, i would like some info on how i can accomplish this, is it possible to build an easy to integrate php+websockets+node.js chat application that can communicate the same way with all platforms whether web or mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Chat with Sencha Touch + node.js + socket.io

This is an example for a sencha touch based chat client which gets messages pushed from a chat-server written in node.js. For the connection between server and client i use socket.io as implementation of websockets.

Comment: Where is the example please?

Comment: please serach with Mobile Chat with Sencha Touch + node.js + socket.io